Bluetooth not responding
I've been using this version since 2023 and this just happened half an hour ago. It was working all the time before this. While i was casually using my laptop, Bluetooth just randomly cut out of nowhere and i cant get it to turn back on. The switch in the settings tab is doing nothing, im turning it on but it still says "Bluetooth Turned Off" and "Turn on to connect devices and recieve file transfers." I've looked through every post i could find but nothing helped. Turning it on through the terminal also didn't help. Running service bluetooth start outputs nothing after i insert my password. sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart doesn't help as well. What can i do to fix this?
Any help is appreciated.

You could rfkill list to see if you brushed the keyboard switch.
